# Accessing data from an already completed callback

Tags: jquery, api

So, I have a script that retrieves an API callback and shows up in Firebug like this:

```
 callbackname({
  "rules": {
    "USA": {
      "currentscore": 57,
      "pass": false
     }
   }
 });
```

The code that makes the call and receives the data is obfuscated. I'm wondering how I can use jQuery to access these variables outside of the original callback or if it's at all possible.

I realize this will be hackish, but for my current endeavor, it makes no difference.

Comment: If the callback is asynchronous, you probably can't, unless you hook into the async function somehow.

Answer (score 0):

To access the data from outside of the callback, simply assign the object to a variable outside of it. E.g.

```
var callbackJSON = null;

function callbackname(data) {
  callbackJSON = data;
}
```